# How to use Asynchronous Comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-3.6

I'm trying to use [Python 3.6's async comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/) in a MacOS Sierra (10.12.2), but I'm receiving a `SyntaxError`.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
print( [ i async for i in range(10) ] )
print( [ i async for i in range(10) if i < 4 ] )
[i async for i in range(10) if i % 2]
```

I am receiving a syntax error for [async loops](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/):

```
result = []
async for i in aiter():
if i % 2:
    result.append(i)
```

All code is copy/paste from the PEP.

Terminal Output:

```
>>> print([i for i in range(10)])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print([i async for i in range(10)])            
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print([i async for i in range(10)])
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print([i async for i in range(10) if i < 4])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print([i async for i in range(10) if i < 4])
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behaves as expected. The issue is that these forms of comprehensions are only allowed *inside* `async def` functions. Outside (i.e in the top-level as entered in your REPL), they raise a `SyntaxError` as defined.

This is stated in the specification section of the PEP, specifically, [for asynchronous comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/#asynchronous-comprehensions):

> Asynchronous comprehensions *are only allowed inside an `async def` function*.

Similarly, for using [`await` in comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/#await-in-comprehensions):

> *This is only valid* in `async def` function body.

As for `async loops`, you'll need both an object that conforms to the necessary interface (defines `__aiter__`) and placed inside an `async def` function. Again, this is specified in the corresponding PEP:

> It is a `TypeError` to pass a regular iterable without `__aiter__` method to `async for`. It is a `SyntaxError` to use `async for` outside of an `async def` function.

Comment: Is there a quick way to call an `async def` function from the REPL and wait for it to finish?

Comment: @tbodt I realize you asked pretty exactly 6 months ago but for anyone else wondering, you can use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(some_async_function())` in the REPL to run the function synchronously.