# Python 3.5: "async with" results in SyntaxError. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine

I am using Python 3.5, which, according to [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) should have access to the `async with` syntax, yet I get a SyntaxError when I try to use it. What am I doing wrong?

```
In [14]: sys.version
Out[14]: '3.5.2 (default, Oct 11 2016, 04:59:56) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)]'

In [15]: async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
  File "<ipython-input-15-9799c5ce74cf>", line 1
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Quoting the page you linked: *"It is a SyntaxError to use async with outside of an async def function."*

Comment: You can not use `async with` without context. Try use it in a async function.

Comment: @vaultah Please move your comment to an answer and I will accept

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317309/how-to-use-asynchronous-comprehensions/41317330#41317330 (Basically same error but different `async` construct)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can not use `async with` without `async` function. As the [docs say](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#new-syntax):

> It is a SyntaxError to use async with outside of an async def function.

But this code will work:

```
async def some_function():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        pass
```

Or have a look at the example from the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#example).

Comment: I think you quoted the wrong section. The correct citation would be the last sentence in the [PEP - 492: "New Syntax" section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#new-syntax): _"It is a `SyntaxError` to use `async with` outside of an `async def` function."_

Comment: @MSeifert thanks, updated!